# How do i check the time complexity of a comprehension

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension

I have gone through many blogs regarding python time complexity and posting my doubt:

In case of list comprehensions how will the time complexity be analysed?

For example:

```
x = [(i,xyz_list.count(i)) for i in xyz_set]
```

where `xyz_list = [1,1,1,1,3,3,4,5,3,2,2,4,5,3]` and `xyz_set = set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])`

So, is the complexity the one line of code `O(n*n*n)` [i.e., `O(n)` for iteration, `O(n)` for list creation, `O(n)` for count function]??

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is quadratic `O(n^2)`:

```
x = [(i,xyz_list.count(i)) for i in xyz_set]

xyz_list.count(i)) #  0(n) operation
```

for every `i` in `xyz_set` you do a `0(n)`  `xyz_list.count(i)`

You can write it using a double for loop which will make it more obvious:

```
res = []
for i in xyz_set: # 0(n)
    count = 0
    for j in xyz_list: # 0(n)
        if i == j: # constant operation 0(1) 
            count += 1 # constant operation 0(1)
    res.append(count) # constant operation 0(1)
```

[Python time complexity](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity)

usually when you see a double for loop the complexity will be quadratic unless you are dealing with some constant number,  for instance we just want to check the first 7 elements of `xyz_list` then the running time would be `0(n)` presuming we are doing the same constant work inside the inner for:

```
sec = 7
res = []
for i in xyz_set: 
    count = 0
    for j in xyz_list[:sec]: 
        ......
```

Comment: @sagargp, no 0(n^2),  it is basically a double for loop

Comment: To be strict, `count = 0` should come between `for i` and `for j`, but that doesn't affect the result at all. So `O(n^2)` remains true.

Comment: Your doesn't have a list creation..If that is added what would the complexity be?

Comment: @sagargp, append is a constant operation,  it has no bearing on the complexity.  we count append count  to the list and the complexity will still be the same, it is no different than `+=`.

Comment: @sagargp, I added a direct translation including the list but as I previously said it makes no difference

Answer (score 6):

The complexities are not necessarily multiplied. In many cases they are just added up.

In your case:
`O(n)` for iteration, and `O(n)` for list creation, and for each new item there is `O(n)` for `count()` which gives `n*O(n)`. The total complexity is `O(n) + O(n) + n*O(n) = O(n*n)`

Answer (score 5):

A list comprehension is nothing special, it is *just a loop*. You could rewrite your code to:

```
x = []
for i in xyz_set:
    item = (i, xyz_list.count(i))
    x.append(item)
```

So we have a loop, and we have a O(n) `list.count()` operation, making the algorithm O(N**2) (quadratic).